# REST API xml request format for Carbon Copies

Tags: docusignapi

we need to send carbon copy to user, i searched for REST API xml format, but did not find suitable example. Please let me know the format for the carbon copies request in xml format for REST API.
we are using the following format, but carbon copy is not working.
can somebody help us on this?

```
<signer>
<recipientId>1</recipientId> 
<routingOrder>1</routingOrder> 
<email>abc@xyz.com</email> 
<name>abc</name> 
</signer>
<signer>
<recipientId>3</recipientId> 
<routingOrder>3</routingOrder> 
<email>abcd@xyz.com</email> 
<name>abcd</name> 
</signer>
</signers>
<carbonCopies>
<carbonCopy>
<recipientId>2</recipientId> 
<routingOrder>2</routingOrder> 
<email>abce@xyz.com</email> 
<name>abce</name> 
</carbonCopy>
</carbonCopies>
</recipients>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear as to exactly what you mean by "carbon copy is not working", but your XML for the Cc recipient looks correct to me. i.e., this format works for me:

```
<carbonCopies>
  <carbonCopy>
    <email>janesemail@outlook.com</email>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <recipientId>2</recipientId>
    <routingOrder>2</routingOrder>
  </carbonCopy>
</carbonCopies>
```

For example, using the following XML, I'm able to create an envelope using a DocuSign Server Template -- mapping the **signer** to the template role **Signer1** and then adding an additional (Cc) recipient.

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes

<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
   <accountId>ACCOUNT_ID</accountId>
   <status>sent</status>
   <compositeTemplates>
    <compositeTemplate>
        <serverTemplates>
            <serverTemplate>
                <sequence>1</sequence>
              <templateId>TEMPLATE_ID</templateId>
            </serverTemplate>
        </serverTemplates>
        <inlineTemplates>
            <inlineTemplate>
                <sequence>2</sequence>
                <recipients>
                  <signers>
                    <signer>
                     <email>johnsemail@outlook.com</email>
                     <name>John Doe</name>
                     <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                     <roleName>Signer1</roleName>
                    </signer>
                  </signers>
                  <carbonCopies>
                    <carbonCopy>
                      <email>janesemail@outlook.com</email>
                      <name>Jane Doe</name>
                      <recipientId>2</recipientId>
                      <routingOrder>2</routingOrder>
                    </carbonCopy>
                  </carbonCopies>
               </recipients>
            </inlineTemplate>
        </inlineTemplates>
    </compositeTemplate>
  </compositeTemplates>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

If I subsequently do a "Get Recipients" request (GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients) for this Envelope, I can see that both the Signer and the Cc got created for the envelope. Here's the "Get Recipients" response (in JSON):

```
{
    "signers": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "johnsemail@outlook.com",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "recipientIdGuid": "733ca7c0-8f52-490c-8dcf-ad3ecd4ecccb",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "03c8a856-c0ae-41bf-943d-ac6e92db66a8",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Signer1",
            "status": "sent",
            "templateLocked": "false",
            "templateRequired": "false"
        }
    ],
    "agents": [],
    "editors": [],
    "intermediaries": [],
    "carbonCopies": [
        {
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "email": "janesemail@outlook.com",
            "recipientId": "2",
            "recipientIdGuid": "74307df2-fed6-4cbd-938e-cff949c06c76",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "2c9e06eb-f2c5-4bef-957a-5a3dbd6edd25",
            "routingOrder": "2",
            "status": "created"
        }
    ],
    "certifiedDeliveries": [],
    "inPersonSigners": [],
    "recipientCount": "2",
    "currentRoutingOrder": "1"
}
```